# Markdown places my table in the end of document when rendering

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown, papaja

I'm creating a pdf document with papaja and r markdown. when i render my document (`apa6_pdf`) it puts the table at the very end of the document. My chunk is in the middle of the document? I read that tables need to go even behind references and before figures, but if i don't want that, can i still change that?

````
```{r creating table 1, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

papaja::apa_table(mytable)

```
````

Comment: You should check the documentation for `apa_table()`, specifically the argument `placement`.

Answer (score 2):

When working with papaja in R Markdown and you want to have your tables displayed within text and not after, you can put `floatsintext: yes` in the YAML front matter. (see the [manual](https://crsh.github.io/papaja_man/r-markdown-components.html#rendering-options) for details).

Comment: As a side note, with the latest version of `papaja` the option has been renamed to `floatsintext` to match the option name used in the `apa6` LaTeX class (`figsintext` still works to ensure backward compatibility, though).